# Exception in an MVC app and dealing with Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following controller in an MVC application with Spring and Hibernate:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/mypage"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    try {

        // Here I call a Service and then a DAO, where I can get HibernateException

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    mv.setViewName("mypage");
    return mv;
```

I'm not sure the exceptions are handled correctly here.

First of all:

- I don't throw any checked exception (HibernateException is also unchecked).
- However I need to catch all the exceptions, because I want to show to the user the same page anyway with a notification error (instead of an error page).
- In my DAO I didn't catch or rethrew any exceptions.

My questions are:

- Is it fine to catch and deal with exceptions in that way?
- Should I also catch HibernateException separately in the controller?
- Should I do something more than just logging?
- Should I also catch the exception in the DAO and then rethrow it? Should rethrow a different type of exception to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

**HibernateException** encapsulates the actual root cause than can provide you enough information for you to generate meaningful user-friendly messages. Read the Exception Handling section of their [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/transactions-demarcation-exceptions.html).

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException,
>   immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close()
>   and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not
>   leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by
>   Hibernate can be treated as recoverable.

This means that other than catching the exception to transform it or wrap it into another kind of exception, catching the exception won't help you: using the session after won't work as expected anyway.

refer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions)